# Same Named columns in different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple worksheets that are built up in somewhat of the same way.
I've written a macro that could be used on each worksheets as it uses the columns that have the same input (like date, volume,..).
As I want to avoid that if someone creates a new column that the macro stops working, I have named the columns. This way if it was column B and it's now D, the macro will keep on working.

The problem that I'm now facing is that I would like to use the same macro on each worksheet but as you can only have one column named "Date_inbound", I'm a bit stuck how to incorporate it further.
I would like to avoid to have different modules for each worksheet and I would like to have it all under one code if any changes should be made.

Is there a way that I can incorporate the referral to a named column that depends on the active sheet?
For example this line of code:
Range("Date_inbound").Cells(i).Value

If I have two sheets for example:

- Product A
- Product B

And if I would name the columns:

- Product_A_Date_Inbound
- Product_B_Date_Inbound

How would I be able to automatically differentiate in the code Range("Date_inbound").Cells(i).Value based on the active worksheet?

Comment: Your columns are named ranges? You could define the names on worksheet level rather than on workbook level (Use Formulas->Name manager to do so). Or define your data as Table and use something like `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Date_inbound").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

When defining a named range, you can set the scope to a specific worksheet. Then you could have identically named ranges on different sheets without conflict.

[image]

Explicitly referencing the worksheet before `Range`

```vb
Sub demo()
    Sheets("Product A").Range("Date_Inbound").Cells(1).Value = "ProductA"
    Sheets("Product B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Date_Inbound").Cells(1).Value = "ProductB"
End Sub
```

---

If you prefer to use workbook-scoped name range (e.g Product_A_Date_Inbound, Product_B_Date_Inbound), updated the code as needed.

```
Sub demo()
    ' Assuming sheet name is "Product A" , "Product B"
    ' Defined name is "Product_A_Date_Inbound", "Product_B_Date_Inbound"
    Dim sFullName As String
    Const S_NAME As String = "_Date_Inbound"
    With ActiveSheet
        sFullName = Replace(.Name, " ", "_") & S_NAME
        .Range(sFullName).Cells(1).Value = .Name
    End With
End Sub
```